# How to keep calling a function when scope variable changes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller that looks like

```
.controller('GraphsController', function($scope, TemperaturePoller, SoundPoller){
    $scope.temperatures = {readings: [], dateTimes: []}
    $scope.temperatures = TemperaturePoller.data;

    $scope.$watch(function(scope) {return scope.temperatures},
                  function(newValue, oldValue) {
                    console.log("Value Changed: " + newValue);
                    $scope.graph(newValue);
                  })

    $scope.graph = function(data) {
        console.log('values changes, refreshing graph');
    }
})
```

and the value is retrieved from `Server` every 10 seconds

```
.factory('TemperaturePoller', function($http, $timeout){
    var data = {};
    var poller = function() {
        $http.get('http://localhost:8080/monitoring/rest/graph/temperature').then(function(r){
            data = extractTemperatureReadings(r.data)
            data.calls++;
            $timeout(poller, 10000)
        });
    }
    poller();

    return {
        data: data
    }
})
```

I want the `$scope.graph` to be called everytime the `$scope.temperature` changes

I see on browser `console.log`, that it is called just once

Value Changed: [object Object]
monitoring.js:19 values changes, refreshing graph

How can I force it to be called every `10 seconds` since I know the data from API is changing?

Comment: You should watch `TemperaturePoller.data`, because that's the thing that changes. Or don't rewrite `data` entirely (in your api callback), just replace contents but leave object reference the same (not sure how to do this properly in JS).

Comment: Can you please explain why do you assign value to a variable twice :
$scope.temperatures = {readings: [], dateTimes: []}
$scope.temperatures = TemperaturePoller.data;
Is it a typo or does it actually does sometime it don't understand?

Comment: @Black0ut, I did because until the data arrives from API, `$scope.temperatures` is undefined and was causing the further statements to be `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Since the data you're watching is an object, set the `objectEquality` flag on the `$watch` function to `true`. This is given as a third parameter.

```
$scope.$watch('temperatures', function(newValue, oldValue) {
     console.log("Value Changed: " + newValue);
     $scope.graph(newValue);
}, true);
```

Comment: That is not updating either, still same result